# SSIS Migrating data from Oracle to SQL Server. Need to find dates before '1900-01-01' and replace with null

Tags: sql-server, oracle, date, ssis, format

I'm trying to migrate data from a Oracle database to SQL Server. The query has invalid dates so I want to change the invalid dates to NULL when I place them in the SQL Server 2012. I'm using SSIS and I'm trying to create a derived column to handle it for me but I can't get the expression right.

The expression I have is :

```
[Date_Column] < 1900-01-01? NULL(DT_WSTR,50) : [Date_Column]
```

This is not the only syntax I tried, I also tried

```
[Date_Column] < "1900-01-01"? NULL(DT_WSTR,50) : [Date_Column]

[Date_Column] < (DT_DBDATE)1900-01-01? NULL(DT_WSTR,50) :[Date_Column]
```

And many others.

Is there a better way to do this?

I'm not too familiar with PL/SQL but if you have a way for me to just edit it in the query rather than using a transformation that would be great!

Also, when I'm trying to migrate the data from Oracle to SQL Server using SSIS, it fails and throws out a data format error. All I am doing is putting the data into a staging table in SQL Server (using an OLE DB source connected to OLE DB destination). The data types are just `DB_TIMESTAMP` but it won't complete. It will only load 1/4th of the data.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

On the Oracle side you can turn dates earlier than 1900-01-01 into NULL values with a CASE expression in your query, e.g.

```
with t as (
   select date '1000-01-01' as date_column from dual
    union
   select date '2000-01-01' as date_column from dual)
select date_column,
       case when date_column < date '1900-01-01' then null else date_column end new_column
  from t

DATE_COLUMN NEW_COLUMN
----------- ----------
1000-01-01            
2000-01-01  2000-01-01
```